# Objective-c convert a parent class to its derived class

Tags: objective-c

I have a custom class named MyImage inherit from UIImage. Now I have a UIImage object, is there any ways to convert it into a MyImage object?

---

Update

Sorry for being unclear.

I cannot use a category because I need to add new properties to my class.

What I want to accomplish is to just let my MyImage object point to the original UIImage object.

---

Update 2

I  tried something like this:

```
- (MyImage*)initWithUIImage:(UIImage *)image {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self = image;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Obvious it does not work.

Also, since UIImage does not have a method named 'initWithImage:(UIImage*)', I cannot write something like

```
myImage = [[MyImage alloc] initWithImage:uiImage];
```

I also tried

```
self = [image copy]
```

But the return value is still a UIImage object, not a MyImage object.

---

Update 3

In MyImage, I need to add 3 properties: url, width, and height. Since I am writing a instant messaging app, and when receiving a new image message, I only have its url, width, and height. Then I assign those to a MyImage object, and download the image in the background.

Now given an original UIImage A, I want to create a new MyImage object B, which points to the same image as A, but with those new properties unassigned. Then I manually assign url, width, and height to B.

to @rmaddy, could you tell me how to write the method

```
[[MyImage alloc] initWithImage:(UIImage*)]
```

?

One way I can come up is first convert the UIImage object to NSData, then use

```
[MyImage imageWithData:]
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: You can write something like `myImage = [[MyImage alloc] initWithImage:uiImage];`. As stated in my answer, this requires adding the `initWithImage:` method to your `MyImage` class.

Comment: Your object is either a `UIImage` or a `MyImage`.  It cannot be both; this would violate the law of non-contradiction.  Maybe it would help if you explained why you want to subclass `UIImage`.  For example, if you're just adding methods to it (something like `downloadWithURL:` is somewhat common), you only need to do that, and then you can use `MyImage` in any class that requires a `UIImage`, because `MyImage` is a kind of `UIImage`.

Comment: Post more details about your `MyImage` class. Without any details it is difficult to offer a concrete answer.

Comment: `UIImage` already has methods to get the size. Why do you need them in your `MyImage` class? What is the URL for? The image or something else?

Comment: @rmaddy, url is for downloading the image from the server. When I receive a new message from another client, I will pass the url, width, and height. At this point, I do not have the image itself, but only its url, width, and height.

Comment: It sounds like `MyImage` should not extend `UIImage`. You should have `MyImage` extend `NSObject` and then have a `UIImage` property along with the properties for URL, width, and height.

Comment: @rmaddy, that's indeed my another thought. I will try it if this problem cannot be solved..anyway, thanks!!

Comment: Your problem is that you are needlessly extending `UIImage`. Solve it by changing your class properly. Don't force a bad design.

Answer (score 0):

I do not necessarily recommend this as a solution, but there is indeed a way to do exactly what you are looking for. It is called ISA Swizzling. Think of it like method swizzling but for Classes instead of methods.

Take a look at the Objective-C runtime's `object_setClass` [[link]](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/object_setClass)

I won't go into it (there are better resources out there), but this is essentially how KVO works. Regardless, it would be helpful if you better described the functionality of your `UIImage` subclass, so that we could help describe why a custom initializer as rmaddy describes is probably the best solution.

Comment: This won't work if `MyImage` requires more memory than `UIImage`.

Comment: Yes, plenty of reasons why you shouldn't use this. But wanted to provide it as an educational alternative. @downvoter, this is a legitimate answer to the question posed, why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote, and my comment was meant to expand on your answer, not criticize it.

Comment: Yeah thanks @AaronBrager, knew it wasn't you. No judgement towards downvoter, but would like to know if they want to contribute further arguments against this method. (again, I wasn't recommending it...)

Answer (score 0):

Your `MyImage` class is a *subclass* of `UIImage`, so if you're creating a new instance you need to properly initialize the superclass as well. `UIImage` doesn't provide a method to do that from another `UIImage` instance, but you can use a `CGImage`, and you can get one of those from the existing image. So do this:

```
- (MyImage*)initWithUIImage:(UIImage *)image {
    if (self = [super initWithCGImage:image.CGImage]) {
        // put any necessary MyImage-specific stuff here
    }
    return self;
}
```